# How to Put listview and recyclerview in linearlayout

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_items"></ListView>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recycler">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I need to add listview and recycler view in one activity but in this i am just getting listview items. Recycler view items are not showing.

new XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/list_items">
    </ListView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/recycler">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It shows listview in 1/4 of the screen and rest of the screen showing the recyclerview.
i want all the items of the listview will show as listview end's recyclerview items start showing.

Comment: use the weightSum property of linearlayout 
android:weightSum="2" and set the weight to listview and recyclerview
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: Hello @ZahoorSaleem i don't want to device space between two i want that first all the arraylist list of listview show. As Listview will finish start recyclerview items. But as you mentioned it divide screen into two parts.

Comment: add android:fillViewport="true" inside Recycler and Listview and put the Linearlayout inside the Scrollview

Comment: why do you need a recycler view in list view

Comment: @PuneetKansal firs option is set weight on both and other one set height of both programmatically by getting height of its child items

Comment: @PuneetKansal What is the goal of merging both lists? So that they look different? or to have 2 data sources? If (1) to make the items look different, consider providing different layouts in `getView` depending on the index, if (2) to have two sources of data, you'll have to use something like an adapter that merges the 2 sources together and behaves like a single source.

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem add android:fillViewport="true" inside Recycler and Listview and put the Linearlayout inside the Scrollview – code works good but problem is showing only one item in the listview not all of the item.

Comment: share the xml file

Comment: Added new xml in above code please check

Comment: Try to use constraintlayout

Comment: @HarshMittal What will be the code for ConstaintLayout

Answer (score 2):

There is one good feature of android designing is **Weight_sum** properties in Linear layout.In your above code make changes as shown below,...

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

As per above code,can add weight sum in parent layout and add weight as per you wish to divide your layout. check by editing above code like,..

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

You will get to know about  how weight some works! 
May answer helps you!

Comment: Hello @Happy Bhimani i have already commented as per your code. That i don't want to divide layout in parts. i want to show list view item then recycler view items.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use a single RecyclerView, making its adapter handling both view types from your ListView and RecyclerView, but if you insist using both ListView and RecyclerView, you can use this ListView subclass

```
public class WrapListView extends ListView {
    public WrapListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 1, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

RecyclerView supports wrap_content out of the box, you just have to call `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to make scrolling smooth

Doing this will void the recycling mechanism of both ListView and RecyclerView, since both view's height are stretched to full length, and no item view is reused/recycled.